# My normalize_friendly_id override is never called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I am very new to `friendly_id` and it matches my need to provide friendly URLs

I have a `Group` model (i.e. a group of users) for which I generate a unique `code` upon creation. FYI, this `code` attribute is set as a unique index in my PostgreSQL database.

```rb
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  include FriendlyId
  friendly_id :code

  after_create :generate_group_code

  private

  def normalize_friendly_id(value)
    super.upcase
  end

  def generate_group_code(size = 8)
    allowed_chars = ("a".."z").to_a
    code = (1..size).map { allowed_chars[rand(26)] }.join while Group.exists?(code: code)

    update(code: code)
  end
end
```

I think I have followed the gem's guide properly, I just want the generated `code` to be upcased in the URLs (i.e. `/group/ABCDEFGH`).

The friendly_id is indeed set as my `code` attribute, but it is not upcased. I placed a `byebug` in the `normalize_friendly_id` method but it is never triggered. What am I missing?

Comment: I worked on it today. Is your need just an way to avoid active record error on touching the uniqueness of `code`? The gem manages it for you as well. For example: with a already code: 'myslug'. Trying the same, it is gonna create like 'myslug-d47fhffh-fh-hfhs-' as your facebook account name. If this is not your need, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sunny's way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69100131/12206696) is probably the way to go in general, as the `slugged` module is required to edit internal methods such as `normalize_friendly_id`.

In my case, I already have a `code` attribute that is unique. Using the `slugged` module would create a new attribute called `slug`, which would be *exactly* the same as my `code`. I want to avoid that duplication.

In the end, I decided to dodge the `friendly_id` gem and directly override the `to_param` method the my model (inspired [by this gist](https://gist.github.com/jcasimir/1209730)):

```rb
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  validates :code, format: { with: /\A[a-z]{8}\z/ }, uniqueness: true, on: :update

  after_create :generate_group_code
  
  # Override the method to allow '/group/MYGROUPA' paths 
  def to_param
    code.upcase
  end

  # A group code is made of letters exclusively.
  # Converting a String (or nil) to an integer leads to 0.
  # In this case, lookup by code, otherwise, lookup by id.
  # Note the 'downcase', which allows URLs to be case insensitive.
  def self.find(input)
    input.to_i == 0 ? find_by_code!(input.downcase) : super
  end

  private

  def generate_group_code(size = 8)
    allowed_chars = ("a".."z").to_a
    code = (1..size).map { allowed_chars[rand(26)] }.join while Group.exists?(code: code)

    update(code: code)
  end
end
```

I'll edit this answer if I encounter any side effect, but for now it works.

Answer (score 1):

The `normalize_friendly_id` is only called when using the `slugged` module to use a `slug` column to store and find by this column:

```rb
friendly_id :code, use: :slugged
```

Using this you can then override the `normalize_friendly_id` method.